# using objc_getClassList in the objective c runtime

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, runtime

In apple's open source runtime documentation (available here:http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-208/runtime/objc-runtime.h) apple provides an example method of getting all the classes in an application. It looks like this:

```
int numClasses = 0, newNumClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
Class *classes = NULL;
while (numClasses < newNumClasses) {
    numClasses = newNumClasses;
    classes = realloc(classes, sizeof(Class) * numClasses);
    newNumClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);
}
// now, can use the classes list; if NULL, there are no classes
free(classes);
```

Sorry if this is a lame question, but what is the purpose of having that while statement in there if we just set numClasses to newNumClasses in the next line? It seems as though the block within the while will get executed just once regardless but i could totally be missing something here. Does anyone have any insights on this?

thanks!

Comment: Notice that `newNumClasses` is set as a result of the `objc_getClassList` call, so if it increases then `numClasses < newNumClasses == true`.

Comment: Yes but won't it only it only execute a single time? Does this code not execute exactly the same way with or without the while statement?

Comment: Not necessarily. If `newNumClasses` is 5 to start with, then the second time `objc_getClassList` is called it returns 10, then it'll execute the while loop again, etc.

Comment: Yes it would, they were showing how you can use NULL to just get the count and add the classes to an existing array.

Comment: @mattjgalloway but the second time its called its got a size limit of numClasses, which is equal to the total number of class according to the initial getClassList call. So how can they be different?

Comment: A new class could be registered between the calls.

Comment: yes but doesn't objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses) return AT MOST numClasses?